# How to preload a config from server, that other controllers will load other resources based on it?

Tags: angularjs

In an AngularJs application, we need to fetch a config json from server. This config is used in several controllers, and there are many controllers will retrieve another resources based on the config.

For now, I'm doing it like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .run(function($http, $rootScope) {
    $http.get('/public/js/config.json')
      .success(function(data) {
        $rootScop.config = data;
      })
  }
  .controller('Controller1', function($http, $scope, $rootScope) {
     $scope.$watch('config', function() {
        if($rootScope.config) {
            $http.get('/public/data/' + $rootScope.config.dataSource1 + ".json")
              .success(funciton(data) {
                $scope.mydata1 = data;
              })
        }
     });
  })
  .controller('Controller2', function($http, $scope, $rootScope) {
     $scope.$watch('config', function() {
        if($rootScope.config) {
            $http.get('/public/data/' + $rootScope.config.dataSource2 + ".json")
              .success(funciton(data) {
                $scope.mydata2 = data;
              })
        }
     });
  })
```

You can see I used `$watch` to watch the `$rootScope.config` and do something based on it.

It works but I find the code is not very good. Is there any better solution?

PS: We are not using angular routes in this project.

Comment: One option that i think is at least better than $rootScope property watch would be to create a async method getConfig() that returns a promise either on rootscope or a service. The controllers now have to make explicit call to `getConfig().then(function(config){//code that uses config});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of watching the `$rootScope`, you could use a service like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .factory('appConfig', function ($http) {
    return $http.get('/public/js/config.json')
      .then(function (resp) {
        return resp.data;
      });
  })
  .controller('Controller1', function($http, $scope, appConfig) {
     appConfig.then(function (config) {
        $http.get('/public/data/' + config.dataSource1 + ".json")
          .success(function (data) {
            $scope.mydata1 = data;
          });
     });
  })
  .controller('Controller2', function($http, $scope, appConfig) {
     appConfig.then(function (config) {
        $http.get('/public/data/' + config.dataSource2 + ".json")
          .success(funciton(data) {
            $scope.mydata2 = data;
          });
     });
  });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if other services would need the config?  Maybe to define their endpoints on other foreign servers.  Would this need to change?  Or, would the other services just accept the `appConfig` service the way the controllers are taking them in here?